# Can I use 2 RJ45 magjacks (PCB mounted) used for pass through..on my PCB?

Tags: pcb, rj45

I need to put a pass through ethernet on my PCB. (rj45 to rj45).
My circuit is similar to this [guy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216473/ethernet-pass-through-over-pcb)..
I want to use my existing components. I have space on my chipplacer(yes I have a chipplacer line) for this magjack [here](https://www.mouser.ie/ProductDetail/Wurth-Electronics/74980111211/?qs=SaTeGCoDkn0e%252bVkSZxqMrQ==).
I would like to use 2 of these magjacks instead of 2 standard rj45s. back to back.
Will this work? (10baseT is OK for me).

Or will the magjacks back-to-back destroy the signal?

Comment: No problem with controlled impedance tracks using differential Coplanar, compute using Saturn PCB exe

Comment: Most likely it will work, but if it is not an internal connection, I don't recommend putting extra magnetics on the signal path, but standard wire-through connections with simple 8P8C connectors.